# Washing machine outlet pipe problem

Tags: plumbing

Hello I’m new here and my plumbing knowledge is not great !! I have just purchased a new washing machine , as last one was leaking . Once we removed old machine we could see the leak was coming from the connection to the outlet pipe that is cemented to the concrete wall . The outlet pipe is flush with the wall hence no room to screw on connection nut to join the pipe . Looks like the old pipe had just been pushed in to connect . How do I fix this ? Thanking you in advance for any help advice .

Comment: A photo would help, but: the outlet should have an air gap, https://www.plumbingsupply.com/how-and-why-air-gaps-are-used.html, i.e., a vertical pipe coming from the wall, with the outlet hose *loosely* inserted (but held in place).

Comment: You will need to rework your drain to meet code.  You should also return the new washer before you use it.

Comment: We will not be able to help you without additional information, preferably in the form of pictures that show the "outlet pipe" and its connection to the sewer/drain.